# No Android Tools in Xamarin Visual Studio

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

For some reason, I have no controls/tools in my "toolbox" window for Xamarin Android development in Visual Studio 2015. In other words, I can't create any objects in the form designer because there are none to drag/drop. [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZHLHrkvUt0&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l#t=114.111502)

Clearly shows that there should be tools in my toolbox just like WinForms... Not sure what's going on. Anyone else experience this?

Answer (score 0):

in a xamarin forms app you have to design your controls in xaml code.
If you start a xamarin Android project you will find the controls in your toolbox.